# How to convert Word (doc) to PDF in linux?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

I have a set of files in **.doc** format, that need to be converted to **.pdf** format. I am using Ubuntu linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch-convert Word-documents to PDF's (free)](http://superuser.com/questions/17612/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-free)

Answer (score 34):

Alternative 1)

```
sudo apt-get install cups-pdf
```

Then navigate to System > Administration > Printing and create a new printer, set it as a PDF file printer, and name it as "pdf".

Then run:

```
oowriter -pt pdf your_word_file.doc
```

Now you'll find your .pdf file in ~/PDF.

---

Alternative 2)

```
sudo apt-get install wv tetex-extra ghostscript  
wvPDF test.doc test.pdf
```

If the tetex-extra package is not available with your distribution, try texlive-base plus texlive-latex-base:

```
sudo apt-get install wv texlive-base texlive-latex-base ghostscript  
wvPDF test.doc test.pdf
```

Comment: in `oowriter -pt pdf your_word_file.doc`, is the printer specified? In my computer, it will try to print to an actual printer instead of a pdf printer.

Comment: How can I change the ~/PDF path to somewhere else ?

Comment: OpenOffice is generally now replaced with LibreOffice, so the command is `lowriter`

Comment: for LibreOffice, the command is 

`lowriter --convert-to pdf your_word_file.doc`

and the default is to output in the current directory.

Comment: `wvPDF` not found in Lubuntu, `wv` version `1.2.9-4.2` is installed

Answer (score 14):

You can use:

```
oowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export doc_file.doc
```

Comment: Short and simple - however, if one is running LibreOffice (or is running OO.org and cannot find `oowriter`) -- the command is `swriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export x.doc`.

Comment: For Libreoffice, this works: `writer -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export file.docx`

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04 with the default LibreOffice, I had to use `lowriter` instead of (oo|s| )writer. Then it worked with the same arguments as above: `lowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export file.docx`. The .pdfs are created in the current directory.

Comment: I like this. On my 3.6.6.2 -convert-to pdf chose writer_pdf_Export as default. Also something to keep in mind - don't have any LO instances open when running this command, otherwise it will just open an empty new document in the GUI. Can this be avoided somehow?

Answer (score 12):

Printing to PDF loses a lot of the document metadata (title, authorship, the headings tree that is used for navigation, and so on).

[Install](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unoconv) [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/), convert with: `unoconv -fpdf file1.doc file2.doc…`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I think the syntax provided by you is wrong.

$ unoconv myfile.doc

It converts to PDF format by default and so you get myfile.pdf on executing the command.

Comment: This is the best solution, it totally handles talking to LibreOffice for you.

Comment: Agreed that this is the best answer. A better answer however, would be one that was as simple as this, but did not require installing the gigantic libreoffice.

Comment: Wow this does a lot more than that. For example you can convert html, doc, docx and more to pdf. For example to convert from html to pdf run `unoconv  --output output.pdf myHtmlPage.html`

Comment: unoconv is deprecrated

Answer (score 11):

If you're running X then you can do it through Open Office.  Since you're about to object to doing it manually, remember there's some nice macro scripts in Open Office so you can [automate it](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Convert_MS_Word.html).  You can do something similar with AbiWord (AbiWord --to=pdf).

If you've not got X then there is antiword, but that just extracts the text - doesn't do any formatting or graphics.  There's also [wvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) which I've used to bulk extract images from doc files, but I've never tried using it to convert doc files to pdfs.

Oh and .docx files may well need something different, but since they're just zipped xml files it shouldn't be too difficult to do something useful with them.  For bulk extracting images you just unzip them and copy the images directory, but I've never needed to convert them in Linux.

Answer (score 10):

If you already install LibreOffice

```
lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf *.doc
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it with [AbiWord](http://abisource.org):

`sudo apt-get install abiword`

Then you can load .doc files in AbiWord's GUI and export to PDF, or from the commandline:

`abiword --to=pdf filename.doc`

Answer (score 2):

I would try using for Linux

```
$ /opt/openoffice.org3.1/program/python DocumentConverter.py test.odt test.pdf
```

For windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3.1\program\python" DocumentConverter.py test.odt test.pdf
```

PyODConverter requires OpenOffice.org to be running as a service and listening on port (by default) 8100; the simplest way to start OpenOffice.org as a service is from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 3.1\program\soffice" -accept="socket,port=8100;urp;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Office is a good way forward, but the conversion fidelity is not always quite right.

If you are after a 100% Linux solution then that is the best way forward. However, if you don't mind a single Windows Box and write a little bit of code to interface with it from your Linux system then [have a look at this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html).

I wrote this post so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 0):

- Open -> Open Office (3.2 in my case)
- Open Document you want to export
- File->Export as PDF
- Press: Export
- Choose file name

Done and Done

Comment: Redundant answer.

Answer (score -2):

- Install OSE VirtualBox from the software center
- Install Windows inside VirtualBox
- Install MS Office in the virtual Windows
- Install `dopdf` in the virtual Windows
- Set `dopdf` as your default printer during the installation.
- Open the `*.doc` in the virtual Office and print it to the `dopdf` virtual printer.
- The `*.pdf` file will appear in the `My Documents` folder of the virtual Windows
- Send it as email attachment to wherever you need to send it.

Comment: if you use MS Office just install "Save as PDF or XPS"
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7

Comment: This is a lot of trouble and unnecessary licenses for simple conversions that can be done natively in linux

Comment: This is a Rube Goldberg machine. Don't use this. There are so many native ways to do it.