# How to convert ,doc file to .pdf in CentOS?

Tags: centos

I have a set of files in .doc format, that need to be converted to .pdf format. I am using CentOS 5.6.

I have referred this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux) in which same thing is done for Ubutu but i am using CnetOS and i tried to install **cups-pdf** package using yum install cups-pdf but I could not get it to install.

In Addition to this i also tried alternative2 of the above link.

Thanks

Comment: Any of the solutions mentioned in the post you linked to should work. The easiest will be using open office (or libreoffice) or AbiWord.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure current versions of OpenOffice.org can read .docs and can write PDF files without assistance from CUPS.

I'd just install OOO and use it's "export as PDF" feature. I'd leave  CUPS alone.

Comment: i want to do this using command line.

Comment: @juned: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=141558

Comment: @juned: http://qugstart.com/blog/linux/openoffice-headless-mode-installation-word-doc-to-pdf-conversion/  and http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/wiki/OpenOfficeConverter