# Convert THOUSANDS of Word (doc) to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion, ubuntu-14.04

I have roughly 30,000 .doc files that I need to convert to PDF. What's the best way to go about this?

I have every flavor of OS you can think of...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch-convert Word-documents to PDF's](http://superuser.com/questions/17612/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-free), [How to convert Word (doc) to PDF in linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux)

Comment: I know this is somewhat of a duplicate, but no one else that asked this question had as many files as I do.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it's still a duplicate question (IMO).  If you'd like newer/different answers to the exist question please earn [some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and place [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.

Comment: Use the aforementioned tools for conversion and write a batch/bash script to loop over the files. Are all files in one directory(tree) or do you have a file with all the path and filenames?

Answer (score 0):

Have a talk with [PDF-Tools AG](http://pdf-tools.com); they have industrial-strength converters (which you do need with this quantity of files to convert), and they also know what they are doing when creating PDF.