# How to convert Word (doc) to PDF in centos6.5

Tags: libreoffice, cups

I used the libreoffice effect is not good, word layout is a mess. Also used OpenOffice,but word2007, WORD2010 use error. Tried cup-pdf, but i do not know how to set the effective without GUI.I want to make a command word to PDF function on the CentOS server.

Comment: Not much to go on for the nature of the problem.  LO and OO can generally handle doc files, but it isn't their native format, so there may be some formatting that isn't run-of-the-mill that they have difficulty with.  Are you sure the document isn't corrupted (looks fine in Word)?  One option might be to use a web service, like https://smallpdf.com/, http://www.sejda.com/, or https://online2pdf.com/ (even if just to verify that the document is convertible).  There are some PDF toolkits to roll your own, but I've never gotten into those.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this command:

```
oowriter -pt pdf file.doc
```

What it is the output?

If pdf-cup is not working you can try with this one:

```
sudo apt-get install wv tetex-extra ghostscript  
wvPDF file.doc file.pdf
```

Refrence: [How to convert Word (doc) to PDF in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux)

Comment: [root@iZ94hgtrav1Z ~]# oowriter -pt pdf file.doc
Failed to open display
Warning: -pt is deprecated.  Use --pt instead.

Comment: wvPDF test.doc test.pdf            Could not find required program 'latex'

Comment: If you do nto have latex in your distribution you can try with: sudo apt-get install wv texlive-base texlive-latex-base ghostscript  
wvPDF test.doc test.pdf