# How convert Docx file to fillable PDF file?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion, adobe-acrobat

How do you convert a Docx file to a PDF containing fillable form fields?

Note, I'm not asking how to [convert a Docx to PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/156189/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-in-linux). That's trivial using Libreoffice or the print dialog. However, that generates effectively a flat file. PDF supports the notion of "form fields" that a user can fill in and then save their changes as a new PDF file. However, other than [Adobe's proprietary tools](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/convert-word-excel-paper-pdf-forms.html), I can't find a way to do this on Linux.

Comment: I'm confused, this appears to be a question about Libreoffice, why is it tagged as being about Microsoft-Word?

Comment: Are you looking for software then? Consider the https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk-on-redhat-or-centos/ as it appears to work on some Linux OSes so test it out when you get a chance.You shouldn't be software shopping here and if you have an actual document in a specific format which you need to convert, consider giving a link to a test document or a screen shot or something to show what you are starting with, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Linux tools, such as the commercial product [Master PDF](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/).

However, there are many online tools, such as [JotForm](https://www.jotform.com/pricing), [PDFescape](https://www.pdfescape.com/windows/) and [PDFfiller](https://fillable-pdf.pdffiller.com/), that let you compose a PDF form online or submit a document. A screenshot of PDFescape's interface is below.

[image: PDFescape interface]

It is likely that some Windows OS PDF tools run under wine. About half the Windows applications I've tried, such as IrfanView and 7-Zip, run quite well in wine, though some others do not work as well, and some won't even start.

*Caveat*: I've not tested the Linux application or the online services.