# Convert a lot of docx files into pdf on macOS

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, automator

After searching an answer for my question I write it here.
I have a lot of docx files and need to convert it to pdf. I have word 2019 installed on macOS Catalina. Is it possible to do somehow with automator or with word 2019? And how?

Comment: Might be able to do it with a macro. Never used Word on a Mac, but you might want to check this out: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-batch-of-doc-files-to/8f5549be-8143-4f0a-8f82-06c855fcb092

Comment: There’s a very similar question at https://superuser.com/questions/338165/convert-batch-of-word-files-to-pdfs-in-mac-os-x/1512168#1512168 . Probably worth checking the answer by Al John as some of the other approaches probably won’t work any more or are more complicated.

Comment: I find a Chinese article "[利用 Automator 将 PPT / Word 批量转换为 PDF](https://jianing.wang/posts/automator-convert-ppt-to-pdf/)", you could use Google to translate and check whether script in this article is helpful. I must honestly say that the script may not be universal for different versions of Office.