# automatically convert word document into PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch-convert Word-documents to PDF’s (free)](https://superuser.com/questions/17612/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-free)

I'm using word 2010, where I can save a word document into PDF. But I'll have to open it, save as etc. Is it a tool or script or something that I can do this automatically without launching word, even if it means I have to use the cmd shell?

Comment: this is what you migh be looking for http://superuser.com/questions/17612/batch-convert-word-documents-to-pdfs-free

Comment: cool! I knew it was possible!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `save as` short cut <kbd>F12</kbd> to save docs as pdf.
Or if you want to set pdf as default file type follow [this](http://www.dkszone.net/how-to-change-default-file-save-format).

Comment: would like to avoid launching word at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it from outside Word, you need a doc to pdf converter tool.  Many open source tools are available that can do this.
You can check this among one of the many sites available: `http://www.doc2pdf.net/`