# "Save as PDF" plugin with Arabic numbers

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion, language, numbering

I use the "Save as PDF" plugin with Word 2007 to generate a PDF document from a DOCX document. It works great except that the Arabic numbers in the Word file have been converted to English numbers in the PDF document. Kindly find two links containing two screen shots explaining the problem.

[image]

[image]

The first image is the generated PDF file with the English numbers highlighted. The second image is the original word file with the Arabic numbers highlighted.

**Update**: Thanks very much Isaac, ChrisF and Wil. I changed the Numeral at word to Context and confirmed that all the numbers are Arabic at the Word file. I still have the problem as the PDF file still have English numbers. (Note: The Arabic numbers called Hindi numbers). I also tried changing the font to Tahoma with no hope.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, because some numbers are in Arabic while some are not!

Try this:

1. Go to **Word Options**
2. Open the **Advanced** tab
3. Find the **Numer** option
4. Change it to **Context**

---

[image: Word Options]

Figure1 - Word Options

---

[image: Numeral Option]

Figure2 - Numeral Option

---

If you still have English numbers, try **Arabic** instead of **Context** for **Numeral** option.

If you still have the same problem, change the font of text to a suitable font like **Tahoma**. You can find more fonts [HERE](http://www.bornaray.com/en_fonts.asp) for download.

Answer (score 1):

in adobe acrobat Press Ctrl-K, goto Languages, and uncheck "Hinid Digits" under "Editing Text in Middle Eastern Languages".

Answer (score 0):

The quickest thing is to try a different method.

If you have the full Adobe Acrobat, you can try printing to the virtual printer rather than the convert button.

If that fails, try to get a different PDF Virtual Printer, such as [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) or [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/)

I see you tagged this as asp.net which is confusing, so if I got this wrong - sorry!

Comment: Also try pdfcreator (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or for a complete list see http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf