# Printing to Power point

Tags: printing, microsoft-powerpoint, documents

Similar to the print to pdf option, where we can choose PDF to be the output format in the print dialog box when printing something from a browser or other applications, I am searching for something which can print to a Power Point file. Is there any such plugin or tool? Also link to a relilable print to pdf tool would be helpful. This essentially would eliminate the export to power point option that the users are asking for in my Silverlight application.

EDIT:

I was looking for print to ppt which is simillar to this for pdf : [How to print documents to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf)

For PDF I found this thread has answers:
[How to print documents to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf)

Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf

Comment: I am looking at printing to a power point file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround if nothing more specific available: print to OneNote/PDF/XPS/... and then cut and paste.