# Convert PDF with Arabic and English Fonts to Word

Tags: pdf, arabic, conversion

I need to convert a PDF file that has arabic and english text to word. A sample page from the file can be found on this link

http://digital-dividend.com/clients/00000217.pdf

I need to do this so the text can be entered in a database. I have tried some pdf to word converters but most of them issues with the Arabic.

Will highly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: None of the programs mentioned here: http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf work ?

Comment: Sathya - thanks for the reply. The post you mentioned show how to create PDFs. What i need is that i already have the PDF file and i need to convert that to Word. And the problem is the Arabic that is in the PDF file. Most PDF to Word converters refuse to handle the Arabic.