# Convert pdf contains utf-8 to word or text files?

Tags: pdf, utf-8, arabic

I have a pdf file that contain arabic text I need to convert this pdf to word for editing 
but when it converted the characters displayed in unreadable format

any suggestion that can help me will be appreciated

Comment: Did you use Acrobat to conver the files or some other process?  What version of Word?  What version of Acrobat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PDF with Arabic and English Fonts to Word](http://superuser.com/q/198229/2357).