# How to copy from arabic PDF file to word?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, arabic

When I copy from Arabic PDF file to word I get only scribble, I have tried to convert the whole file to word but I have get the same also.

Comment: Do u have the font (same Arabic font in PDF) in your computer? It could be just a font issue if you are unable to copy. Also try to convert PDF to Word online. This may get you the Arabic text in Word file

Comment: converting online did not solve the issue, I will check the font and let you know

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is a computer readable document it might work copy-pasting it in notepad ++ -works fine for me.. (as long as there is no latin letters involved: it makes parts of the text being placed wrong, which can be rather disturbing) .. 
If someone has a solution for that I would be very grateful!
(maybe even after all these years it would help this guy as well: [Convert PDF with Arabic and English Fonts to Word](https://superuser.com/questions/198229/convert-pdf-with-arabic-and-english-fonts-to-word?rq=1))