# How to display  m by n pages in Adobe Reader 10?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I want to view a PDF document that contains images only. Displaying them in m by n is very convenient to compare one with the others.
Shortly speaking, how to display m by n pages in Adobe Reader 10?

Comment: You really can't. I looked, and tried a couple of popular alternative PDF reader programs, but I could not find anything to do what you want.

Comment: @KCotreau: OK no problem. I will use LaTeX to create a new PDF document where each page contains 4 pages of the original document. It can be done easily using `pdfpages` package. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that in Adobe Reader and many other PDF viewers the best you can get is 2 by N pages. In *Adobe Reader* set *Page Display* as *Two Page Scrolling*.

**Possible workaround**: Printing to PDF file *Multiple pages per sheet*.

In *Adobe Reader* go to *Print*, in *Page Handling* set *Page Scaling* to *Multiple pages per sheet* and set desired m by n pages per sheet.

Many PDF printing tools are listed in [How to print documents to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around that is good for 2 x 2.

Open your document and go to View --> Page Display --> Two Page scrolling

Then, set the page zoom to 50%.