# Save existing PDF to 4 pages per page?

Tags: print-to-pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print documents to pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf)

I have several large PDFs for professional related reading. Its topping out over 1500 pages. I want to print it out at a professional printer since I don't have a good desktop printer.

The printers charge per impression. If I print one page, 4 pages or all 1500 pages on one piece of paper, I pay for that one impression on the page. So if its 0.10 a page I pay 0.10. If I double side, its two impressions so 0.20. Thinner book but still same cost.

In most PDF readers I'm able to print a pdf as 4 pages to one page. I have to provide the printer a final copy of the PDF to print. I don't have the option of asking them to print 4 to a page.

I was thinking the only way to get around this is to "print" the PDF to file and have in the print options to save as 4 to a page. Distiller crashes when I try it (I used copy at work on my desktop).

Any ideas? I want to save paper and trees!

Comment: You could spell out the conditions of printing in advance very clearly with the printer, and then make it a condition of payment that the specific print option be used -- if they agree to this, then this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) or [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php#Features).

By selecting one of those virtual pdf printers you can print the file with 4 pages into one page output setting in advanced tab.

Comment: Thanks! Bullzip works wonderfully. Most of the other PDF programs were crashing when I was trying to do this. I was trying to use LaTex but the document wasn't copy/pasting correctly into a text editor or MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used distiller but [PDFcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) has worked well for me in printing out massive files to PDF. If possible i might also suggest splitting the file up and merging the output with [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) since it might bee excessive memory use that's tripping up distiller