# Save web page to pdf in background

Tags: pdf, download

I'm looking for a tool I can use to save the active web page into a pdf file in the background - so I can keep on surfing. I clip a *lot* and evernote/onenote are just too slow or require user intervention.

Comment: Which OS? Which browser? Does it _have_to be saved as PDF specifically?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a [PDF printer](https://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf) and then, when you want to save a page as PDF, just print it to PDF.

Comment: excellent advice, thanks. this beats all the crappy firefox extensions hands down.